# display login window as list of users

Tags: debian, login, xfce, powerpc

How do you display the login window as a list of users instead of having to type the username?  I have Debian XFCE on a Powerbook G4.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you are using GDM (that screenshot looks a bit like GDM), go into the gdm settings, e.g. with `gdmsetup`, and enable the [face list browser](http://projects.gnome.org/gdm/docs/2.18/gdmsetupusage.html) or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Also in gdmsetup

Click the Users tab,  and add the usernames that you want to have displayed in the face browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think xdm supports this. Install [Gdm](http://packages.debian.org/gdm) or [Kdm](http://packages.debian.org/kdm). You don't need to use a display manager (a system setting) that matches your desktop environment (a user setting).

Comment: That picture looks nothing like xdm though, so it must be a more modern display manager.   (At least upstream xdm has no ability to choose language or session.)